# Opening link in popup-webview like Twitter

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, popup, storyboard

Twitter opens links in a sort of in-app browser which jumps from the bottom into fullscreen mode, see the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I get something like this in my own app? I dont know how this is called so my current google results are not resolving my question. I am not sure if this is a webview or safari extension use or something else.

I also wonder how to implement this in xcode-storyboard. Should I create a new viewcontroller which jumps to the front with a fullscreen webview? I hope someone can give me an example or website with a tutorial/explaination.

[Preferably examples in swift, I don't know a lot about Objective_C]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [modal presentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) of a [ViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) containing a web-view.

Answer (score 4):

[SVWebViewController](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController) makes this really easy, it's a drop-in browser view controller with all the standard bells and whistles.

Objective C:

```
SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://google.com"];
[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Swift:

```
let webViewController = SVModalWebViewController(address: "http://google.com")
self.presentViewController(webVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```